# Is it possible to use data mapping with a custom field?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I was wondering if I can link a custom field to a cms block/slot (Layout)? If not, can I write a custom plugin that allows this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I had similar functionality. You have to override administration component to add your field to the list and your logic to load the data.

Comment: do you have an example how I can fix this?

Comment: you can check out this component `vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/text/config/sw-cms-el-config-text.html.twig`

Comment: I'm looking at this piece of code, but can't figure out how I can add the custom fields to the data mapping list. For example: category.customFields.dummyText

Comment: This is api to return entity schema for data mapping:
`vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Api/Controller/InfoController.php:158` and the js service to store data mapping `vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/src/core/service/entity-mapping.service.js`